# How to find the length of checkbox checked inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All I would like to find the `length` of checked checkboxes.

- [My CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrPzwE)
- In My `CodePen` I have created sample reference, I can able to find the length while clicking on `check box`, what I exactly looking is while clicking of `ALL input` `check box`, all checkbox should be checked.
- For example: while `click (or) checked` rose input check box the result of length shows like `1`, so when we `click (or) checked` All input `check box` the expecting result should be like `4`, when clicking on `All check box` input the `rose, white, blue` need to checked.
- How to do while clicking on one input check box others check box need to be checked?.

**Html:**

```
<div id="checkboxlength" class="css">

  <div class="blue">
    <input type="checkbox"><span>All</span>
  </div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" ><span>rose</span>
 </div>

 <div>
   <input type="checkbox" ><span>blue</span>
   </div>


<div>
   <input type="checkbox"><span>white</span>
    </div>

<div class="green">
   <span  id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> checked
    </div>

</div>
```

**Java Script:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var $checkboxes = $('#checkboxlength  input[type="checkbox"]');

    $checkboxes.change(function(){
        var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);

        $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes').val(countCheckedCheckboxes);
    });

});
```

**ID:**

```
checkboxlength
```

**Result Code:**

```
<div>
     <span  id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> checked
    </div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `Id` or a `class` to the `check all` checkbox, like this you can eliminate it while counting the checked checkboxes and also detect it while clicked so you can check/uncheck others checkboxes.

```js
var $checkboxes = $('#checkboxlength  input[type="checkbox"]');
$checkboxes.change(function(){
    /*if the clicked checkbox has check_all id
     then check all other checkboxes if this one is checked 
     and vise versa */
    if($(this).is("#check_all"))
        $checkboxes.prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
        
    $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length);
});
```

```css
.css{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.green{
  color:red;
}

.blue{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxlength" class="css">
   <div class="blue"><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"><span>All</span></div>
   <div><input type="checkbox" ><span>rose</span></div>
   <div><input type="checkbox" ><span>blue</span> </div>
   <div><input type="checkbox"><span>white</span> </div>
   <div class="green"><span  id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> checked</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it's working perfectly.....

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#all").click(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});

$(document).on('change', function() {
  $('#count-checked-checkboxes').html($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)
})
```

```css
.css {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.green {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxlength" class="css">
  <div class="blue">
    <input type="checkbox" id="all"><span>All</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>rose</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>blue</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>white</span>
  </div>
  <div class="green">
    <span id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> checked
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think include "All" checkbox as checkbox checked is not worth

Comment: I was about the comment the same , some user downvotes only to get attention to their answers .. not fair

Comment: Thats true sorry, didnt read well the question, gonna give you upvote

Comment: Sure, Can you edit the post? I have vote blocked until edit

Comment: hey, thank you guys `Amani` answer is working to perfectly thanks for the help.

Comment: @R.ManiSelvam I can't see the difference between both answers, it's just a different approach

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var $checkboxes = $('#checkboxlength  input[type="checkbox"]');
 $checkboxes.change(function () {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('blue'))
  {
   $("input:checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
   $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text($(":checked").length > 0 ? $(":checked").length-1 : 0);
  }
  else
  {
   var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
   $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);
   $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes').val(countCheckedCheckboxes);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxlength" class="css">
        <div class="blue">
            <input type="checkbox"><span>All</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox"><span>rose</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox"><span>blue</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox"><span>white</span>
        </div>
        <div class="green">
            <span id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> checked
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer your answer is based on text like :- .next('span').text() == "All") so can you fix it without text like `id` or `value` ?.... I am exactly looking for your answer only, please fix it as a id or value thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help I got the answer I give you upvote thanks...

Comment: @R.ManiSelvam Updated the above code to check for class `blue` instead of "Span > All". The code has been changed to `if ($(this).parent().hasClass('blue'))`. Just an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $checkboxes = $('#checkboxlength  input[type="checkbox"]');
  $("#all").click(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
  $checkboxes.change(function() {
    var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);

    $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes').val(countCheckedCheckboxes);
  });

});
```

```css
.css {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.green {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxlength" class="css">

  <div class="blue">
    <input type="checkbox" id="all"><span>All</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>rose</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>blue</span>
  </div>


  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"><span>white</span>
  </div>

  <div class="green">
    <span id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> checked
  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I got the answer I give you upvote thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can find the length of selected checkbox using
var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

Answer (score 1):

You can add only one class for "All" checkbox and then separate your JS to two reausable functions `countChecked()` and `toggleAll()`. Here are the snippets:

** HTML:

```
  <div class="blue">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggleAll"><span>All</span>
  </div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" ><span>rose</span>
 </div>

 <div>
   <input type="checkbox" ><span>blue</span>
   </div>


<div>
   <input type="checkbox"><span>white</span>
    </div>

<div class="green">
   <span  id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> checked
    </div>




</div>
```

** JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $checkboxes = $('#checkboxlength  input[type="checkbox"]:not(".toggleAll")');

    $checkboxes.on('change', function(){
        countChecked();
    });
  function countChecked(){
    var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);

  }
  function toggleAll(checked){
    if(checked){
      $checkboxes.each(function(){
        this.checked = true;
      });
    }else{
      $checkboxes.each(function(){
        this.checked = false;
      });
    }
  }

  $('.toggleAll').on('click', function(){
     toggleAll(this.checked);
    countChecked();
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I got the answer ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="checkboxlength" class="css">

  <div class="blue">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this);"><span>All</span>
  </div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" ><span>rose</span>
 </div>

 <div>
   <input type="checkbox" ><span>blue</span>
   </div>


<div>
   <input type="checkbox"><span>white</span>
    </div>

<div class="green">
   <span  id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> checked
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
       function toggle(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i] != source)
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hope this works

Comment: Thanks for your help I got the answer I give you upvote thanks...